# Wordpress meta query not working to search using ACF custom field value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I have a wordpress query I want to search custom post type using an ACF custom field value but the query is not working, I am entering correct values but result is null.

Wordpress Code

```
function webdev_search_apple_post_data()
{
 $args = array(
  'post_type' => sanitize_text_field($_GET['post_type']), // custom post type
  'meta_query' => array(
   array(
// here I tested both "meta_key" and "key" for all of the following.
    'meta_key' => 'model_no', // ACF custom field
    'meta_value' => sanitize_text_field($_GET['model_no']),
    'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
   )
  )
 );
 $query = new WP_Query($args);
 if ($query->have_posts()) {
  while ($query->have_posts()) {

   var_dump($query->the_post());
   die();
  }
 }
 wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_webdev_search_laptop_post_data', 'webdev_search_apple_post_data');

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_webdev_search_laptop_post_data', 'webdev_search_apple_post_data');
```

jQuery code

```
$("laptop-model-input").on("keyup", function (event) {

  var pattern = /^A\d{4}$/;
  var enterKeyCode = 13;
  var model_no = $(this).val();
  let targetEl = $(this);

  if (event.which === enterKeyCode && pattern.test(model_no)) {
    $("#laptop-post-data-div").html('<img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/Dual-Ring-1s-200px-1.gif" style="max-width:35px;">');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
      data: {
        'model_no': model_no,
        'post_type': 'laptop_serv',
        'action': 'webdev_search_laptop_post_data'
      }, success: function (result) {
        $("#laptop-post-data-div").html(result);
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I tried the above code but it's returning NULL

Comment: Is that WP PHP code inside of a of the `laptop_post_data` function? If you run your query without JS and hardcoded values for `sanitize_text_field($_GET['model_no'])` and `sanitize_text_field($_GET['post_type'])` do you get a result? Did you try testing after each `if` statement? Try testing at each step in your functions to see if you're actually getting the data you expect.

Comment: yes, let me edit the WordPress code.

Comment: This `webdev_search_laptop_post_data` in your AJAX doesn't match this `webdev_search_apple_post_data` in your WP code.

Comment: That is fine, because apple one is registering the function to the WordPress, and the WP function is invoking, problem is only that the query result is null.

Comment: I know how AJAX works in WP, however, your AJAX callback isn't calling the function you are showing us - so there will be no query. Also, is your `model_no` an integer? If so you should use `meta_value_num` instead of `meta_value`

Comment: `// here I tested both "meta_key" and "key" for all of the following.` - it _needs_ to be the variants without the `meta_` prefix, when you have a `meta_query`. The versions with the prefix are only for when you pass parameters on the "top level" of the arguments array.